# Not able to locate corresponding java file of .feature file

Tags: selenium, ant, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am running selenium with cucumber-jvm and junit framwork.I modified [this](http://www.opencredo.com/2013/07/02/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/) example as per my requirement. I need to run test through ant file, so I created corresponding ant file, my feature file is running correcting and it's also suggesting on cmd to implement @Given, @When,@Then etc regular expression, But I am also creating this steps in java file and providing path that file's package in glue parameter of @cucumber.option in my test file. But it's not picking properly.

Here is my some ant file code

```
  <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="out/cucumber-junit-report"/>
    <java classname="cucumber.api.cli.Main" fork="true" failonerror="false">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        <arg value="--format"/>
        <arg value="junit:out/cucumber-junit-report.xml"/>
        <arg value="--format"/>
        <arg value="pretty"/>
        <arg value="--format"/>
        <arg value="html:out/cucumber-html-report"/>
        <arg value="src/test/resources"/>
    </java>

    <junitreport todir="out/cucumber-junit-report">
        <fileset dir="out">
            <include name="cucumber-junit-report.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="out/cucumber-junit-report"/>

    </junitreport>
</target>
```

and here is my testclass code

```
 package com.cucumber;

 import com.cucumber.stepdefs.AddRecordStep;
 import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
    glue = {"com.cucumber.pageobjects"}
   )
 public class AddRecordTest {

  }
```

I checked many link everylink is saying use glue and define path but I am not able to get solution by using this. Below is my package structure's Image

[image]

I am stuck here. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of `not picking properly`?

Comment: I mean it's not locating the corresponding java file of feature file where I defined all steps.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your glue parameter is not correct. It seems you are glueing the pageobject instead of the stepdef. If your step definitions are in `AddRecordStep` class then your glue parameter should be `glue = {"com.cucumber.stepdefs"}`

Another note, if your stepdefs are in the same or in subpackages as your RunCukes then cucumber would automatically find them for you and glue parameter in that case becomes optional.